# Can´t figure out why routing is not working

Tags: angular

Just trying to learn angular2. After reading tutos and researching around I decided to code a demo working using all common features.

Trying to routing between pages and I am completely lost. I will try to post the most important part of my code, so please, let me know if I am in the good way, if I should try another approach, and why is not working?

**environment_main.ts**

```
import {bootstrap} from "angular2/platform/browser";

import {AppComponent} from "./environment_app.component";
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { CarouselAppRoutes } from './carousel.routes'

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ provideRouter(CarouselAppRoutes)]);
```

*AppComponent contains an html page with the links between pages.*

I am importing the next files, in the head of my **index.html**:

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.33.3/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.20/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.6/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.6/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.6/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      System.config({
        transpiler: 'typescript',
        typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true },
        packages: {'app': {defaultExtension: 'ts'}},
        map: { 'app': './app' }
      });
      System.import('app/environment_main')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>

    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
```

**carousel.routes.ts**

```
import { SociosComponent } from './socios.component';
import { CarteleraComponent } from './cartelera.component';
import { AppComponent } from './environment_app.component';

export const ContactsAppRoutes = [
    { path: '', component: AppComponent },
    { path: 'socios', component: SociosComponent },
    { path: 'cartelera', component: CarteleraComponent }
]
```

I am getting the next error (for now):

[image: Angular Error]

Thanks mates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `angular 2.0.0-beta.6` but importing from `'@angular/router';` @angular syntax came with `rc.0`  so you mixed up your versions.

Source: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-rc0-2016-05-02

Comment: Thanks @echonax. So, following your link, I should change my initials import for using rc.0. And install by command provided. Isn´t?

Comment: @EliasMP ehm I don't recommend that. I recommend using the latest version of angular2 which is 2.4.3 right now. You can check our documentation section on how to get started with angular2 https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angular2/789/getting-started-with-angular-2#t=201701171604195421563

Comment: Thanks @echonax for your efford. I read an old tuto... So, I will start tomorrow again from the beginning. Cheers mate.

Comment: @EliasMP Glad I could help :-)